# Finding monthly payment for ordinary simple annuity with varying interest rates?

Tags: investing, interest-rate, interest, accounting, repayment

I've been working at this question for some time now and I'm quite stuck. Some help would be greatly appreciated. I can figure out recurring payments by themselves, but I'm drawing a blank when it comes to annuities and varying interest rates.

> A woman has reached her retirement age of 65
>   on October 15, 2015. She invests $300,000 and
>   buys an annuity with monthly payments, first
>   payment due on November 15, 2015 and the
>   final payment due on July 15, 2039. What size
>   monthly payment does she receive if the interest
>   rate is j(12) = 6% for the 1st 5 years and j(12) = 3.9%
>   thereafter?

Again, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Taking first a simple case, based on the example here: [Calculating the Present Value of an Ordinary Annuity](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/03/101503.asp).

[image]

If the first two periods had interest rate 10% the calculation would be

```
pv = 1000 (1/1.1^1 +
           1/1.1^2 +
           1/(1.1^2*1.05^1) +
           1/(1.1^2*1.05^2) +
           1/(1.1^2*1.05^3)) = 3986.16
```

or

[image]

where

```
m = 2
n = 5 - m
c = 1000
r1 = 0.10
r2 = 0.05
```

By induction

[image]

Check

```
pv = ((1 + r1)^-m (1 + r2)^-n (-c r1 + 
     c (1 + r2)^n (r1 + (-1 + (1 + r1)^m) r2)))/(r1 r2) = 3986.16
```

Now applying this formula to the OP's case. Oct 2015 to July 2039 is 285 months.

```
m = 60
n = 285 - m = 225
r1 = 0.06/12
r2 = 0.039/12
pv = 300000

pv = ((1 + r1)^-m (1 + r2)^-n (-c r1 + 
     c (1 + r2)^n (r1 + (-1 + (1 + r1)^m) r2)))/(r1 r2)

∴ c = (pv r1 (1 + r1)^m r2 (1 + r2)^n)/(-r1 +
      (1 + r2)^n (r1 + (-1 + (1 + r1)^m) r2))

∴ c = 1765.57
```

Assuming the interest rates are [nominal compounded monthly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_interest_rate#Calculation), the monthly payment is $1765.57

Answer (score 0):

Another way of looking at the transaction to arrive at the correct answer of @Chris Degnen:

Consider that the original investment of $300,000 is divided into two amounts.

The first, **A1**, is used to fund a five-year ordinary annuity, making monthly payments of **R**, at an interest rate of 6% per year, compounded monthly.

So:

A1 = R x (1-1.005^-60) / 0.005 = 51.72556075 x R

The balance of the $300000, **A2**, is left to grow for 60 periods at 0.5% per period, so that it becomes **A3**:

A3 = A2 x 1.005^60 = 1.348850153 x A2

This amount A3 is then used to fund a 225 month ordinary annuity of R per month at 3.9% compounded monthly:

A3 = R x (1-1.00325^-225) / 0.00325 = 159.4221506 x R

So, from these two results:

A2 = A3 / 1.348850153 = 159.4221506 x R / 1.348850153 = 118.1911499 x R

So:

A1 + A2 = 300000 = 51.72556075 x R + 118.1911499 x R
 = 169.9167107 x R

So that:

R = 300000/169.9167107 = 1765.5709